# Declaring variables restricted to a specified range within Java

Tags: java, function, variables, math

I am trying to declare variables that lie within a certain range that will act as parameters for any given function of which they are part of. I have three variables at the minute.

```
class xvalues {

double x1;

double x2;

double x3; }
```

I want to do this in such a way that I can define the variables in their own class say 'xvalues' (with restrictions where for example x1 is in the range (0, inf), x2 is in the range (4, 8), and x3 > 0) so that I can then take xvalues as my parameter for my function and then enter x1, x2 and x3 freely within  my function.

for example taking a function such as;

```
static double f1(xvalues)
{
    return 5*x1 + x2 + 3*x3
}
```

and a return of null if the values are outside of the range.

Comment: you could investigate this [library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/) for this purposes, but I'm not sure that this could help

Comment: Not completely sure what you're asking, but you could check values used to instantiate an instance of `xvalues` in the class's constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by throwing `IllegalArgumentException` in your setters:-

```
public class XValues {
    private Double x1;
    private Double x2;
    private Double x3;

    public XValues(Double x1, Double x2, Double x3) {
        setX1(x1);
        setX2(x2);
        setX3(x3);
    }

    public void setX1(Double x1) {
        if (x1 < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("x1 can't be negative");
        this.x1 = x1;
    }

    public void setX2(Double x2) {
        if (x2 < 4 || x2 > 8) throw new IllegalArgumentException("x2 must be in range (4, 8)");
        this.x2 = x2;
    }

    public void setX3(Double x3) {
        if (x3 < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("x3 can't be negative");
        this.x3 = x3;
    }

    // GETTERS here
}
```

Then when you try to initialize the object or set illegal values, an exception will be thrown.

```
XValues xValues = new XValues(-1.0, 2.0, 3.0); //java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: x1 can't be negative
```

---

You can also throw exception in getters and return null from your method, as you requested, like this:-

```
static Double f1(XValues xValues) {
    try {
        return 5 * xValues.getX1() + xValues.getX2() + 3 * xValues.getX3();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```